# Change indexes in array by groups in table rows

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I've got a problem with change indexes in array by group. I want change index but only this elements with specific group. Now my code is wroking but change indexes in whole array. This is my code:

```
function moveRow (arr, old_index, new_index) {


    arr.splice(new_index, 0, arr.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return arr;
```

}

And this is my mockup db array:

```
 export const dbProductGroupsParameter: ProductGroupParameter[] = [
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'Produkt 1',
    code: 'sdadas',
    description: 'Opis 1',
    position: 1,
    group: 1,
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Produkt 2',
    code: 'sdadas2',
    description: 'Opis 2',
    position: 2,
    group: 1,
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Produkt 3',
    code: 'sdadas3',
    description: 'Opis 3',
    position: 3,
    group: 1,

  },
  {
    id: '4',
    name: 'Produkt 4',
    code: 'sdadas4',
    description: 'Opis 4',
    position: 1,
    group: 2,

  },
  {
    id: '5',
    name: 'Produkt 5',
    code: 'sdadas5',
    description: 'Opis 5',
    position: 2,
    group: 2,

  },
  {
    id: '6',
    name: 'Produkt 1.1',
    code: 'sdadas3265444',
    description: 'Kolejny Opis 1.1',
    position: 1,
    group: 3,
  },
  {
    id: '7',
    name: 'Produkt 1.1',
    code: 'sdadas3265444',
    description: 'Kolejny Opis 1.1',
    position: 2,
    group: 3,
  }
]
```

I use this array in table rows, and I grouping products. For example I want change index only in products group 2.
Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: What is the type of parameter `arr` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forget about this. arr is dbProductGroupsParameter. I need this to fake api operation

Comment: So how can you compare `if (new_index >= arr)` ?

Comment: you're right, it's just the remnant of the previous code. I'll correct